# github3 pagination of search_users results

Tags: python, github-api, github3.py

I am trying to paginate the results of the search_users method of github3. For example I have the following code:

```
connection = github3.login("<my_username>", password="<my_password>")
query = "location:new+york language:ruby"
users = connection.search_users(query, per_page=30)
```

However, when I iterate over users, the iteration goes through all the search results (e.g. for the above users this is roughly 16,000). Is there an option to offset the results by specifying the page I want to fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is currently no way to do that with github3.py.** We can add this as a potential feature for 1.0 though. The potential usage would look like

```
 users = connection.search_users(query, start_page=10)
```